# Install httpd on local repository in CentOS 8

Tags: rpm, yum, centos8

I have one centos8 server with internet connectivity, i refer to [this discussion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/259640/how-to-use-yum-to-get-all-rpms-required-for-offline-use) and create local repository for **httpd**. i copy the local repository to new centos8 server (this server never install **httpd** yet). when i ran command: `yum --disablerepo=\* --enablerepo=offline-httpd install httpd` i get the errors:

```
No available modular metadata for modular package 'httpd-2.4.37-21.module_el8.2.0+494+1df74eae.x86_64', it cannot be installed on the system
No available modular metadata for modular package 'httpd-filesystem-2.4.37-21.module_el8.2.0+494+1df74eae.noarch', it cannot be installed on the system
No available modular metadata for modular package 'httpd-tools-2.4.37-21.module_el8.2.0+494+1df74eae.x86_64', it cannot be installed on the system
No available modular metadata for modular package 'mod_http2-1.11.3-3.module_el8.2.0+486+c01050f0.1.x86_64', it cannot be installed on the system
Error: No available modular metadata for modular package
```

But if i copy this local repository to other machine, which was install httpd and was removed, i can install successfully.
I spent much time to investigate but i have not understand yet. Can anyone help to explain?